# zip argument #1 must support iteration (não entendi esse erro)

Tags: python

Tenho o seguinte código.

```
  v1 = [1,2]
v2 = [2,1]

def vector_add(v, w):
    '''Soma entre dois vetores'''
    return [v_i + w_i for v_i, w_i in zip(v,w)]

def vector_subtract(v, w):
    '''Subtrai elementos correspondentes'''
    return [v_i - w_i for v_i, w_i in zip(v,w)]

print('Soma -> ', vector_add(v1, v2))
print('Subtração -> ', vector_subtract(v1, v2))
```

Que está funcionando normalmente. Porém, tenho mais um no qual aparece o erro.

```
def vector_sum(vectors):
    '''Soma de todos os elementos do vetor'''
    result = vectors[0] #Result recebe o primeiro valor do vetor
    for vector in vectors[1:]: #Depois passa por todos os outros
        result = vector_add(result, vector) #E adiciona ao resultado
    return result

vetorX = [5, 5, 5, 5, 20]
print('Soma de todos os elementos do vetor -> ', vector_sum(vetorX))
```

Isso me retorna o seguinte erro:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         7 
>         8 vetorX = [5, 5, 5, 5, 20]
>   ----> 9 print('Soma de todos os elementos do vetor -> ', vector_sum(vetorX))
>
> in vector_sum(vectors)
>         3     result = vectors[0] #Result recebe o primeiro valor do vetor
>         4     for vector in vectors[1:]: #Depois passa por todos os outros
>   ----> 5         result = vector_add(result, vector) #E adiciona ao resultado
>         6     return result
>         7
>
> in vector_add(v, w)
>         4 def vector_add(v, w):
>         5     '''Soma entre dois vetores'''
>   ----> 6     return [v_i + w_i for v_i, w_i in zip(v,w)]
>         7 
>         8 def vector_subtract(v, w):
>
> TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

Por que acontece esse erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip), `zip` recebe vários objetos iteráveis (como listas ou tuplas, por exemplo) como parâmetros.

No seu caso, você criou `vetorX = [5, 5, 5, 5, 20]` e passou esta lista para `vector_sum`.

Dentro da função `vector_sum`, pegou o primeiro elemento da lista (`result = vectors[0]`). Neste ponto, `result` é igual a 5. Na primeira iteração do `for`, você passa esse valor (5) para `vector_add`, que por sua vez passa-o para `zip`.

Só que o número 5 não é um objeto iterável, e é isso que está sendo dito na mensagem de erro ("*zip argument #1 must support iteration*").

---

Não está claro o que você quer que seja o resultado. Se quiser somar todos os números de `vetorX`, por exemplo, basta fazer `sum(vetorX)`.

Se o objetivo é gerar uma lista em que cada elemento é somado com o primeiro número de `vetorX` (exceto pelo próprio primeiro elemento), então fica assim:

```
vetorX = [5, 5, 5, 5, 20]
primeiro = vetorX[0]
result = [i + primeiro for i in vetorX[1:]]
print(result) # [10, 10, 10, 25]
```

Enfim, independente do que estiver tentando fazer, `zip` é útil para percorrer duas ou mais listas simultaneamente. Se você só tem uma lista (no caso, `vetorX`), não tem porque usar `zip`.